# Entity Framework 6 triggers and notify app with db changes

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-6, eventtrigger

I am relatively new to EF and I was tasked with researching Triggers within EF (using  the `EntityFrameworkCore.Triggered`).
The scenario is this: a person has a handheld device (i.e. scanner) and scans a product into inventory. This action inserts the data into the SQL Server table.

As soon as that happens, I want another application to receive the notification so that another user can do his/her assigned task(s).

I thought EF Triggers would be able to do this rather than using SQLTableDependency.

Any advice/pointers?

Comment: Assuming that Application1 handles insertions it should notify all subscribers that insertion was done. Notification may be done in a lot of ways  It's not clear what connections your applications so it's hard to tell something specific

Comment: @DespeiL Thank you for the reply. Let's see if I can be a little clearer. Data from an app/device sends data to SQL and into a table. This should send a message to another app informing of a new data insertion. I can achieve this with the SqlTableDependency with no issues other than that of enabling the broker. I am looking for a similar way to achieve this with EF.

Comment: If your app  is client  application it shouldn't have any direct connection to your SQL db server. And if your app is server application (some API) than after insertion just send some notifications about it using something like kafka or webhooks.